# Can't use wireless internet through USB

Tags: 10.04, wireless, internet-connection

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid Lynx). I want to use wireless Internet on Ubuntu and thus need to install Idea Net Setter(ISP) for the same. In the USB drive I can find some files, one of the files read as below..:

--How to Install----------------------

- You need login as root *

  1. Run "tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2"
  2. Run `./install` in TERMINAL to install MobilePartner

  eg: # bash //install

  1. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.
  2. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct
  3. Finish installing

--How to run--------------------------
* From shortcut in desktop

- Run MobilePartner in your install path
  eg: # //MobilePartner
- Plug in your device, it will run automatically (Not supported in Xandros)

I inserted the USB and tried to change my directory but it didn't work:

```
vipul@vipul-desktop:~$ cd /
vipul@vipul-desktop:/$ cd media
vipul@vipul-desktop:/media$ ls
Idea Net Setter
vipul@vipul-desktop:/media$ cd Idea Net Setter
bash: cd: Idea: No such file or directory

Then I directly pasted tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2 in the terminal and it didn't work:

vipul@vipul-desktop:/media$ tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2
tar: linux_install.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Then I copied the whole installation program into my home folder, changed directories, ran it again and still nothing happened:

```
vipul@vipul-desktop:~$ cd Idea Net Setter
vipul@vipul-desktop:~/Idea$ ls
AutoRun.exe autorun.sh install_linux Startup.ico
AUTORUN.INF Idea Net Setter Linux SysConfig.dat
vipul@vipul-desktop:~/Idea$ tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2
tar: linux_install.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
vipul@vipul-desktop:~/Idea$ cd Linux
vipul@vipul-desktop:~/Idea/Linux$ tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2
tar: linux_install.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
vipul@vipul-desktop:~/Idea/Linux$ ls
7zr DataCard_Verify MobilePartner.bin SysConfig.dat
data.bin install readme.txt
```

Please help. I'm clueless and don't know what to do ?

Comment: To change to a directory that has a space in the name enclose the name in double quotes or use Idea*

Comment: @ToDo I would recommend to turn it to an answer with an example perhaps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys problem solved with newer versions of Ubuntu. If you are using older version install `sakis3g` and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

To change to a directory that has a space in the name enclose the name in double quotes or use Idea*

Example:

```
cd "Idea Net Setter"
```

or

```
cd Idea*
```

The latter would work only if there was only one directory starting with Idea.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable root first, so in the terminal it should be `root@vipul`. I think in Ubuntu, follow these steps:

1. `$sudo passwd root`      // this enables root account
2. Enter new password for root
3. `$sudo sh -c 'echo "greeter-show-manual-login=true" /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf'`//this enables a manual login when the machine boots
4. Then login as `root` as username and `password` with the new password you entered then you will be logged in as root.

Answer (score 0):

How to install your Mobitel USB Dongle..
(Ubuntu 12.04.2)

1.You need login as root

2.cd /

3.bash /media/Mobitel/install_linux

'install_linux' file should be in your usb dongle.
/media/Mobitel is the file path to 'install_linux' file

4.If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.

5.If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct

6.Finish installing

ENJOY!!